# Preloading a lot of images, stop a preloading screen

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to preload 20 pictures. I have written this code, but I'm not sure it works. Even though they don't pixelate, they appear strange, by flashing and lagging. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
$(window).on("load", (function () {
   PrepareImgs();
   console.debug('loaded');
}));
var sectionArray = ["whoAreWe", "video", "web", "community", "charity"];
var imgArray = [];
function PrepareImgs() {
 // console.debug("PrepareImgs started");
 for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
     for (var j = 1; j <= 4; j++) {
         var zdj = "Assets/Images/CroppedAndCleaned/" + sectionArray[i] + "/pp" + j + ".jpg";
         imgArray.push(zdj);
     }
 }
 LoadImages();
}

function LoadImages() {
// console.debug("LoadImages started");
var i = 0;
$(imgArray).each(function () {
    // console.debug("loop started");
     var img = new Image();
     $(img).attr('src', imgArray[i]);
     img.src=imgArray[i];
     console.debug(i);
    // function preloadImage(url)
    // {
    //     var img=new Image();
    //     img.src=url;
    // }
     img.onload = function () {
         console.debug("Internal loop started");
         i+=1;

         if (i == $(imgArray).length)
             HideLoader();
     }
 });
}
function HideLoader() {
 // console.debug("HideLoader Started");
 setTimeout(function () {
     $('body').addClass('loaded');
 }, 1);
}
```

Comment: I think the main issue lies within your `onload` handler. Two issues apparent to me are that `onload` is asynchronous; each image's load event will fire at a different time depending on how long it takes to load, and probably not in the order you expect. The increment to `i` may not be affecting the `i` in the outer scope. Also, you don't need to pass `imgArray` into `jQuery()` in order to get the length. As is, it's probably returning `0` or `1` instead of `20`.

Comment: Yes, it's returning 0 all the time which is confusing. so should I stop the loop until the event onload is completed? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to follow this example, 
it loads image and appends them to the DOM once all of them are loaded.

It uses `Promises`.

```js
function preloadImages(...images) {

  return Promise
    .all(
      images.map((src, i) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        src = `https://lorempixel.com/400/200/${src}/Image-Number-${i}`;
        const img = $('<img />');

        return img
          .attr('src', src)
          .on('load', () => resolve(img))
          .on('error', reject)
      }))
    )
  ;
}; 


preloadImages('sports', 'food', 'business', 'animals', 'nightlife', 'fashion')
  .then(res => {
    console.log('images loaded');
    
    return res.forEach($img => $img.appendTo('body'))
  })
;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you explain the .then(res=>  part?

Comment: [`Promise.prototype.then`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) accepts a callback that will invoked when the promise is resolved.

Comment: Is it like a pseudocode? My IDE is yelling at me for using =>

Comment: it's `ES2015`, you should have a good support for it... What kind of browser are you using? Click on the blue button `Run code snippet`

Comment: I see it works here. I'm using Chrome. I edited it saying that the IDE doesn't like it. I'm using PHP Storm and WebStorm

Comment: `Preferences > Languages & Frameworks > Javascript` and set `Javascript language version` to `Ecmascript 6`

Comment: So I need to transpile it from like ts to js? Sorry I'm not really good with js

Comment: it depends on your browser support requirements, you may or you may not!